# Python sum of elements in list greater than any number

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum

I want to sum the elements in my list with a certain condition.

For example;
`myList = [1,8,12,17,3,26,5]`

I would like to sum numbers greater than or equal to 10   in this list.

`output: 55`

`sum(myList> = 10)` I tried this function but it didn't work

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter the list to include only the desired numbers, then sum the result of that

```
 sum(filter(lambda x: x>=10, myList))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
sum(e for e in myList if e >= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize a variable with zero and sot you list with the given condition and add the sorted number in the variable
you can simply us

1. myList = [1,8,12,17,3,26,5]
   a=0
   for i in myList:
       if i<=10:
          a+=i
   print(a)
2. Out will be 17